# Issues with accessing a single file from two (or more) different machines?

Tags: java, linux, synchronization, filesystems, distributed-computing

I have a bucket with large number of files in it. (File size below 500kb).

I want to send data to another endpoint and to do it fast I have to set up a `multithreaded environment on N different machines.`

Every machine has an access to the file bucket and the Threads will move the files to different directories. My question here is:

`What will happen if one thread on machine-1 is already moving the file and at the same time thread from machine-2 tries to move the same file` ?

Will it throw an exception for thread-2 saying File not found ? Or both threads may get chance to move same file to different locations. (Which is not desirable as I don't want to process same file twice.)

If it throws any kind of exception it's fine for me as I can catch the same and proceed with next available file. But if not is there any other mechanism to lock the file between different physical machines ?

Thanks for an time and help !!

Comment: This is why modern OSes have file locking.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Its Linux file system , does it guarantee file lock ?

Comment: I'd presume so. But "Linux" is ambiguous... There are a lot of Linuxes out there

Answer (score 0):

No. An OS will not allow you to relocate the same file from two different threads or applications. File locking is a rather important feature of, I dare say, most operating systems.

That said, I am a bit concerned about your proposed solution. Yes, you will get an exception if you try to move a file that does not exist but this amounts to abuse of the idea of exceptions. Exceptions should only be thrown in exceptional conditions and a missing file, in this case, is definitely on exceptional. In fact, it is absolutely expected.

Your proposed solution would could set up a rather odd "feeding frenzy" of threads contending for files. If you have enough of these threads trying to access a file it is possible that some of your threads may actually just spend time handling exceptions rather than doing any real work.

To solve this issue I would suggest a synchronization mechanism of some sort from which each thread could draw a "file move assignment" such as a queue. This would make your solution more efficient and scalable. Without such a mechanism you will find yourself putting out fires and using bubblegum solutions like `Thread.Sleep`...

- Redis ([as a queueing mechanism](http://redis.io/commands/rpoplpush))
- [Apache Zookeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org/)
- [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/)
- Just about any RDBMS
- etc.

Comment: Thanks for an answer Paul. I am aware of synchronization for multithreaded application running on individual machine. Not sure how I will be able to manage between distributed systems , if I use master salve it will be prone to single point of failure.

Comment: @user3026263 You're prone to a single point of failure already by having a single bucket. If you align your synchronization mechanism with your current architecture your risk will not be that much higher. I will update my answer with some distributed synch ideas.

Comment: The bucket is on the disk which is accessible from all machine. And lot of other systems use it as well. Is there any possible way without running application on it ? I will check out the links who shared as well..

Comment: @user3026263 Yes, it is totally possible. I was just thinking that hosting the synch server on the same machine might be simpler. By the way, how do you "know" when to take the next file and where to send it? it's possible that you already have a solution in place that you don't realize.

Answer (score 0):

Totally agree with Paul.

A way to do this is to have another thread (that runs on a machine holding the bucket) that serves these operations and has a queue of queries from different threads. This will eliminate errors on file move (just don't forget to check if the file still exists).